# Creating a result piecewise from stateful computation, with good ergonomics

Tags: haskell, api-design, generic-programming, higher-kinded-types

I'd like to write a function

```
step :: State S O
```

where `O` is a record type:

```
data O = MkO{ out1 :: Int, out2 :: Maybe Int, out3 :: Maybe Bool }
```

The catch is that I'd like to assemble my `O` output piecewise. What I mean by that, is that at various places along the definition of `step`, I learn then and there that e.g. `out2` should be `Just 3`, but I don't know in a non-convoluted way what `out1` and `out3` should be. Also, there is a natural default value for `out1` that can be computed from the end state; but there still needs to be the possibility to override it in `step`.

And, most importantly, I want to "librarize" this, so that users can provide their own `S` and `O` types, and I give them the rest.

My current approach is to wrap everything in a `WriterT (HKD O Last)` using [Higgledy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higgledy)'s automated way of creating a type `HKD O Last` which is isomorphic to

```
data OLast = MkOLast{ out1' :: Last Int, out2' :: Last (Maybe Int), out3' :: Last (Maybe String) }
```

This comes with the obvious `Monoid` instance, so I can, at least morally, do the following:

```
step = do
   MkOLast{..} <- execWriterT step'
   s <- get
   return O
       { out1 = fromMaybe (defaultOut1 s) $ getLast out1'
       , out2 =  getLast out2'
       , out3 = fromMaybe False $ getLast out3'
       }

step' = do
    ...
    tell mempty{ out2' = pure $ Just 42 }
    ...
    tell mempty{ out1' = pure 3 }
```

This is code I could live with.

The problem is that I can only do this *morally*. In *practice*, what I have to write is quite convoluted code because Higgledy's `HKD O Last`  exposes record fields as lenses, so the real code ends up looking more like the following:

```
step = do
   oLast <- execWriterT step'
   s <- get
   let def = defaultOut s
   return $ runIdentity . construct $ bzipWith (\i -> maybe i Identity . getLast) (deconstruct def) oLast 

step' = do
    ...
    tell $ set (field @"out2") (pure $ Just 42) mempty
    ... 
    tell $ set (field @"out3") (pure 3) mempty
```

The first wart in `step` we can hide away behind a function:

```
update :: (Generic a, Construct Identity a, FunctorB (HKD a), ProductBC (HKD a)) => a -> HKD a Last -> a
update initial edits = runIdentity . construct $ bzipWith (\i -> maybe i Identity . getLast) (deconstruct initial) edits
```

so we can "librarize" that as

```
runStep
  :: (Generic o, Construct Identity o, FunctorB (HKD o), ProductBC (HKD o))
  => (s -> o) -> WriterT (HKD o Last) (State s) () -> State s o
runStep mkDef step = do
    let updates = execWriterT step s
    def <- gets mkDef
    return $ update def updates
```

But what worries me are the places where partial outputs are recorded. So far, the best I've been able to come up with is to use `OverloadedLabels` to provide `#out2` as a possible syntax:

```
instance (HasField' field (HKD a f) (f b), Applicative f) => IsLabel field (b -> Endo (HKD a f)) where
    fromLabel x = Endo $ field @field .~ pure x

output :: (Monoid (HKD o Last)) => Endo (HKD o Last) -> WriterT (HKD o Last) (State s) ()
output f = tell $ appEndo f mempty
```

this allows end-users to write `step'` as

```
step' = do
    ...
    output $ #out2 (Just 42)
    ...
    output $ #out3 3
```

but it's still a bit cumbersome; moreover, it uses quite a lot of heavy machinery behind the scenes. Especially given that my use case is such that all the library internals would need to be explained step-by-step.

So, what I am looking for are improvements in the following areas:

- **Simpler internal** implementation
- **Nicer API** for end-users
- I'd be happy with a **completely different approach** from first principles as well, as long as it doesn't require the user to define their own `OLast` next to `O`...

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t just do `step = do { ... ; out2 <- return $ Just 42 ; ... ; out3 <- return $ Just 3 ; ... ; return O{..}` (using [`-XRecordWildCards`](https://kodimensional.dev/recordwildcards#construction))?

Comment: @bradrn different branches come to setting different parts, or none at all.

Comment: @bradrn here's a real example: https://github.com/gergoerdi/clash-intel8080/blob/master/src/Hardware/Clash/Intel8080/CPU.hs

Comment: Thanks for giving me an example, but which part of that file should I be looking at? At first glance I can’t figure out which part is relevant.

Comment: @bradrn all of it starting from `cpu`. E.g. some microcode operations change the address bus, some want to write to RAM, ...

Comment: @bradrn perhaps `acceptInterrupt` is a good example. It is the only way the `irqAck` output pin is set - all other branches of `cpu` need to leave it at its default (`False`) value.

Comment: I think I understand now — are you saying that there are many functions which only output one field of `O`? In that case, can’t you just do `step = do { ... ; out2 <- fnForField1 ; ... ; out3 <- fnForField2 ; ... ; return O{..} }`, similarly to my original comment?

Comment: @bradrn If you look at `cpu`, you can see there is no factoring of it into computing individual fields that wouldn't also completely obscure what is really going on there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207012/discussion-between-bradrn-and-cactus).

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a very satisfactory solution because it's still complex and the type errors are horrific, but it tries to achieve two things:

- Any attempt to "complete" the construction of the record without having specified all mandatory fields results in a type error.
- "there is a natural default value for `out1` that can be computed from the end state; but there still needs to be the possibility to override it"

The solution does away with the `State` monad. Instead, there's an extensible record to which new fields are progressively added—therefore changing its type—until it is "complete".

We use the [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record), [sop-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core) (these for HKD-like functionality) and [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) (for the `Reader` monad) packages.

Some necessary imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-partial-type-signatures #-}
import           Data.RBR (Record,unit,FromRecord(fromRecord),ToRecord,RecordCode,
                           Productlike,fromNP,toNP,ProductlikeSubset,projectSubset,
                           FromList,
                           Insertable,Insert,insert) -- from "red-black-record"
import           Data.SOP (I(I),unI,NP,All,Top) -- from "sop-core"
import           Data.SOP.NP (sequence_NP)
import           Data.Function (fix)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (Reader,runReader,reader)
import qualified GHC.Generics
```

The datatype-generic machinery:

```
specify :: forall k v t r. Insertable k v t 
        => v -> Record (Reader r) t -> Record (Reader r) (Insert k v t)
specify v = insert @k @v @t (reader (const v))


close :: forall r subset subsetflat whole . _ => Record (Reader r) whole -> r
close = fixRecord @r @subsetflat . projectSubset @subset @whole @subsetflat
  where
    fixRecord 
        :: forall r flat. (FromRecord r, Productlike '[] (RecordCode r) flat, All Top flat)
        => Record (Reader r) (RecordCode r)
        -> r
    fixRecord = unI . fixHelper I
    fixHelper 
        :: forall r flat f g. _
        => (NP f flat -> g (NP (Reader r) flat))
        -> Record f (RecordCode r)
        -> g r 
    fixHelper adapt r = do
        let moveFunctionOutside np = runReader . sequence_NP $ np
            record2record np = fromRecord . fromNP <$> moveFunctionOutside np
        fix . record2record <$> adapt (toNP r)
```

`specify` adds a field to an extensible HKD-like record where each field is actually a function from the completed record to the type of the field in the completed record. It inserts the field as a constant function. It can also override existing default fields.

`close` takes an extensible record constructed with `specify` and "ties the knot", returning the completed non-HKD record.

Here's code that must be written for each concrete record:

```
data O = MkO { out1 :: Int, out2 :: Maybe Int, out3 :: Maybe Bool } 
         deriving (GHC.Generics.Generic, Show)
instance FromRecord O
instance ToRecord O

type ODefaults = FromList '[ '("out1",Int) ]

odefaults :: Record (Reader O) ODefaults
odefaults =
      insert @"out1" (reader $ \r -> case out2 r of
                                       Just i -> succ i
                                       Nothing -> 0)
    $ unit
```

In `odefaults` we specify overrideable default values for some fields, which are calculated by inspecting the "completed" record (this works because we later tie the knot with `close`.)

Putting it all to work:

```
example1 :: O
example1 = 
      close
    . specify @"out3" (Just False)
    . specify @"out2" (Just 0)
    $ odefaults

example2override :: O
example2override = 
      close
    . specify @"out1" (12 :: Int)
    . specify @"out3" (Just False)
    . specify @"out2" (Just 0)
    $ odefaults

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do print $ example1
       print $ example2override
-- result:
-- MkO {out1 = 1, out2 = Just 0, out3 = Just False}
-- MkO {out1 = 12, out2 = Just 0, out3 = Just False}
```

Comment: This answer is an adaptation of the technique described here https://discourse.haskell.org/t/adventures-assembling-records-of-capabilities/623

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am currently using for this: basically the same Barbies-based technique from my original question, but using `barbies-th` and `lens` to create properly named field lenses.

I am going to illustrate it with an example. Suppose I want to collect this result:

```
data CPUOut = CPUOut
    { inputNeeded :: Bool
    , ...
    }
```

1. Create Barbie for `CPUOut` using `barbies-th`, add `_` prefix to field names, and use `lens`'s `makeLenses` TH macro to generate field accessors:

```
declareBareB [d|
data CPUOut = CPUOut
   { _inputNeeded :: Bool
   , ...
   } |]
makeLenses ''CPUState
```

2. Write `update` s.t. it works on partial values that are wrapped in the `Barbie` newtype wrapper:

```
type Raw b = b Bare Identity
type Partial b = Barbie (b Covered) Last

update 
    :: (BareB b, ApplicativeB (b Covered)) 
    => Raw b -> Partial b -> Raw b
update initials edits = 
    bstrip $ bzipWith update1 (bcover initials) (getBarbie edits)
  where
    update1 :: Identity a -> Last a -> Identity a
    update1 initial edit = maybe initial Identity (getLast edit)
```

3. The role of the `Barbie` wrapper is that `Barbie b f` has a `Monoid` instance if only all the fields of `b f` are monoids themselves. This is exactly the case for `Partial CPUOut`, so that is what we are going to be collecting in our `WriterT`:

```
type CPU = WriterT (Partial CPUOut) (State CPUState)
```

4. Write the generic output assignment combinator. This is what makes it nicer than the approach in the original question, because the `Setter'`s are properly named field accessor lenses, not overloaded labels:

```
(.:=) 
    :: (Applicative f, MonadWriter (Barbie b f) m) 
    => Setter' (b f) (f a) -> a -> m ()
fd .:= x = scribe (iso getBarbie Barbie . fd) (pure x)
```

5. Example use:

```
startInput :: CPU ()
startInput = do
    inputNeeded .:= True
    phase .= WaitInput
```